# Incorrect url when trying to download sources jitpack.io

Tags: android, github, gradle, android-jetpack-compose, jitpack

I recently encountered an issue where my library sources from jitpack.io wouldn't load.

**Gradle error**

```
Could not resolve com.github.RavenZIP:WorkShop:1.3.0@aar.
Could not get resource 'https://jitpack.io/com/github/RavenZIP/WorkShop/1.3.0@aar/WorkShop-1.3.0@aar.pom'.
Could not GET 'https://jitpack.io/com/github/RavenZIP/WorkShop/1.3.0@aar/WorkShop-1.3.0@aar.pom'. Received status code 400 from server: Bad Request
```

I'm guessing this is due to an incorrect url. He should be like this

```
https://jitpack.io/com/github/RavenZIP/WorkShop/1.3.0/WorkShop-1.3.0.aar
```

**settings.gradle.kts**

```
@Suppress("UnstableApiUsage")
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven("https://jitpack.io")
    }
}
```

Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

Comment: Gradle version 8.4